# Why does the name of an implicit seem to affect its scope resolution in this example?

Tags: scala, implicit, play-json

I am writing a simple JSON serializer for `java.io.File` just stingifying the path:

```
import java.io.File

import play.api.libs.json._
import Implicits.File._

object Implicits {
  object File {
    implicit val format: Format[File] = new Format[File] {
      override def writes(o: File): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)
      override def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[File] = js.validate[String].map(f => new File(f))
    }
  }
}

final case class Bar(path: File) 

object Bar {
  implicit val format: Format[Bar] = Json.format
}
```

I find that the above does not work:

```
No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for java.io.File in the implicit scope
```

However, if I change the name of `Implicit.File.format` to `Implicit.File.fmt`, it works fine.

Why does the name collide in this case when it should be the *type*, `Format[File]`, that the implicit scope resolver should care about?

I'm using play-json 2.6.7.

Comment: Maybe a macro issue. You can file a ticket at https://github.com/playframework/play-json

Comment: I think it is because of collision of the names Imlicit.File.format and Bar.format. You can rename Bar.format instead to fix.

Comment: @igorpcholkin This is literally what my question said.

Comment: @cchantep That's my guess, too. I opened an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the name collide in this case when it should be the type, `Format[File]`, that the implicit scope resolver should care about?

Because it does care about the name as well.

> > [The actual arguments that are eligible to be passed to an implicit parameter of type T fall into two categories. First, eligible are all identifiers x that can be accessed at the point of the method call **without a prefix** and that denote an implicit definition or an implicit parameter. An eligible identifier may thus be a local name, or a member of an enclosing template, or it may be have been made accessible without a prefix through an import clause.](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters)

At the line `implicit val format: Format[Bar] = Json.format`, `format` means `Bar.format` and not `Implicits.File.format`, so `Implicits.File.format` isn't eligible as an implicit by this rule. And it isn't in a companion object, so it isn't covered by the second category either.

Comment: Hmm. I've been using `implicit val format ...` all over my code since I started writing scala and this is the first time I've seen a name collision.

Comment: But I'd guess you did this in companion objects, and that's covered by a separate rule.

Comment: Ah ha! Good inference.